# How do I poison an SVM with manifold regularization?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, support-vector-machine, adversarial-ml, causation

I'm working on Adversarial Machine Learning, and have read multiple papers on this topic, some of them are mentioned as follows:

- Poisoning Attacks on SVMs: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.6389.pdf
- Adversarial Label Flips on Support Vector Machines

However, I am not able to find any literature on data poisoning for SVMs using Manifold regularization. Is there anyone who has knowledge about that?

Comment: I found the following Youtube video: [Poisoning Attacks against Support Vector Machines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dBasP-rhlY). Is it close to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think, one could generate a data set, with a random variable in each component of the data vector, add this data to the training data set, and then shuffle the combined data set.

Comment: Can you please clarify how this answers the question?